# what brand/make is the laptop articulated arm in sleeping pod?

Tags: iss, computing

I saw a video of Sunny Williams

she moved the laptop around. Go to time position 1:34. Is this articulated arm available to purchase for consumers on Earth?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the ISS articulated arm could support a laptop's weight in normal earth gravity?

Comment: @DJohnM Indeed, from the movements in the film it looks like it won't.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a cropped,annotated still from the video showing the arm.

[image]

The arm can be found in the [ISS Intravehicular Equipment Catalog](http://everyspec.com/NASA/NASA-JSC/NASA-JSC-PUBS/JSC-28533E_29700/) as MULTIUSE BRACKET PART NO. SEG33107631-301, pictured therein (in a low-res fashion).

[image]

A vendor is not given, but we in Spaceflight Training colloquially referred to these gadgets as "Bogen arms".  The online Bogen catalog does not show an exact match, but [this](https://bogentripodparts.com/accessories/1486.html) is close.

[image]